# What is the error, on Windows 10 does not work on Linux all the ok (python, cv2)?

Tags: python, opencv3.0

Here is code on Linux without problems on Windows writes a bunch of errors(

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX


id = 0


names = ['None', 'serg', 'mama', 'Ticher', 'Dima', 'TTTTTW'] 


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640) 
cam.set(4, 480) 


minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

while True:
    ret, img =cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
        gray,
        scaleFactor = 1.2,
        minNeighbors = 5,
        minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
       )

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])


        if (confidence < 100):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        else:
            id = "unknown"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  

    cv2.imshow('camera',img) 

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff 
    if k == 27:
        break


print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mistake:

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

I can't understand what the problem is .. It seems to have installed everything correctly. On Linux, everything works without interruption and correctly.